# Error : Object must implement IConvertible while trying to populate Radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, objectdatasource

I'm currently facing a problem while trying to populate my grid that 
its datasource is basically an `Object Data Source` like this:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
  <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <RowIndicatorColumn>
      <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
    </RowIndicatorColumn>

    <ExpandCollapseColumn>
      <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
    </ExpandCollapseColumn>
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TitleChoiceIncident"
            HeaderText="TitleChoiceIncident" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="TitleChoiceIncident" UniqueName="TitleChoiceIncident">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ValueChoiceIncident"
            HeaderText="ValueChoiceIncident" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="ValueChoiceIncident" UniqueName="ValueChoiceIncident">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idAgir" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idAgir" SortExpression="idAgir" UniqueName="idAgir">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idUtilisateur" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idUtilisateur" SortExpression="idUtilisateur"
            UniqueName="idUtilisateur">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idEmetteur" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idEmetteur" SortExpression="idEmetteur" UniqueName="idEmetteur">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idTypeAction" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idTypeAction" SortExpression="idTypeAction"
            UniqueName="idTypeAction">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idEntreprise" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idEntreprise" SortExpression="idEntreprise"
            UniqueName="idEntreprise">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idFamille" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idFamille" SortExpression="idFamille" UniqueName="idFamille">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idProjet" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idProjet" SortExpression="idProjet" UniqueName="idProjet">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idGroupeContact" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idGroupeContact" SortExpression="idGroupeContact"
            UniqueName="idGroupeContact">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idOrdinateur" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idOrdinateur" SortExpression="idOrdinateur"
            UniqueName="idOrdinateur">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idParent" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idParent" SortExpression="idParent" UniqueName="idParent">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idEtatIncident" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idEtatIncident" SortExpression="idEtatIncident"
            UniqueName="idEtatIncident">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idSousCategorie" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idSousCategorie" SortExpression="idSousCategorie"
            UniqueName="idSousCategorie">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="date" HeaderText="date"
            SortExpression="date" UniqueName="date">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="heure" HeaderText="heure"
            SortExpression="heure" UniqueName="heure">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="durée" HeaderText="durée"
            SortExpression="durée" UniqueName="durée">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="priorite" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="priorite" SortExpression="priorite" UniqueName="priorite">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="blocage" DataType="System.Boolean"
            HeaderText="blocage" SortExpression="blocage" UniqueName="blocage">
        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="fait" DataType="System.Boolean"
            HeaderText="fait" SortExpression="fait" UniqueName="fait">
        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="facturable" DataType="System.Boolean"
            HeaderText="facturable" SortExpression="facturable" UniqueName="facturable">
        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="alerterAgir" DataType="System.Boolean"
            HeaderText="alerterAgir" SortExpression="alerterAgir" UniqueName="alerterAgir">
        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="dateRappel" DataType="System.DateTime"
            HeaderText="dateRappel" SortExpression="dateRappel" UniqueName="dateRappel">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="descriptionAgir"
            HeaderText="descriptionAgir" SortExpression="descriptionAgir"
            UniqueName="descriptionAgir">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="cheminFichier" HeaderText="cheminFichier"
            SortExpression="cheminFichier" UniqueName="cheminFichier">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="objet" HeaderText="objet"
            SortExpression="objet" UniqueName="objet">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="lieu" HeaderText="lieu"
            SortExpression="lieu" UniqueName="lieu">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="dateSaisit" DataType="System.DateTime"
            HeaderText="dateSaisit" SortExpression="dateSaisit" UniqueName="dateSaisit">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="dateAgir" DataType="System.DateTime"
            HeaderText="dateAgir" SortExpression="dateAgir" UniqueName="dateAgir">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="isAgenda" DataType="System.Boolean"
            HeaderText="isAgenda" SortExpression="isAgenda" UniqueName="isAgenda">
        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="isAgendaPerso" DataType="System.Boolean"
            HeaderText="isAgendaPerso" SortExpression="isAgendaPerso"
            UniqueName="isAgendaPerso">
        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="isIncidentGen" DataType="System.Boolean"
            HeaderText="isIncidentGen" SortExpression="isIncidentGen"
            UniqueName="isIncidentGen">
        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="dateDebut" DataType="System.DateTime"
            HeaderText="dateDebut" SortExpression="dateDebut" UniqueName="dateDebut">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="dateEtatIncident"
            DataType="System.DateTime" HeaderText="dateEtatIncident"
            SortExpression="dateEtatIncident" UniqueName="dateEtatIncident">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="isPause" DataType="System.Boolean"
            HeaderText="isPause" SortExpression="isPause" UniqueName="isPause">
        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idTypeDemande" DataType="System.Int32"
            HeaderText="idTypeDemande" SortExpression="idTypeDemande"
            UniqueName="idTypeDemande">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TempsEstime" HeaderText="TempsEstime"
            SortExpression="TempsEstime" UniqueName="TempsEstime">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Acceptation" HeaderText="Acceptation"
            SortExpression="Acceptation" UniqueName="Acceptation">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="Accord" DataType="System.Boolean"
            HeaderText="Accord" SortExpression="Accord" UniqueName="Accord">
        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DerniereDateModif"
            DataType="System.DateTime" HeaderText="DerniereDateModif"
            SortExpression="DerniereDateModif" UniqueName="DerniereDateModif">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idExchange" HeaderText="idExchange"
            SortExpression="idExchange" UniqueName="idExchange">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false" UniqueName="ImageColumnValider">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonValidation" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/validation.gif"
                        CommandName="Submit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("idAgir")%>' ToolTip="Valider le ticket"
                        OnClick="Submit_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Êtes vous sûr de vouloir valider ce ticket?');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false" UniqueName="ImageColumnDecliner">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonDecliner" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/croix.png"
                        CommandName="Decline" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("idAgir")%>' ToolTip="Décliner la proposition"
                        OnClick="Decline_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Êtes vous sûr de vouloir décliner la proposition?');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
  </MasterTableView>

  <HeaderContextMenu EnableAutoScroll="True"></HeaderContextMenu>
</telerik:RadGrid>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
        SelectMethod="GetNewAgirsByClient" TypeName="DBAccess.DAOAgir">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="idContact" SessionField="contact" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I get this error and I don't understand why?.
Does anybody know where this might come from ?

**EDIT:** This is the place where I select my data :

```
public static List<Agir> GetNewAgirsByClient(int idContact)
{
    DataClassesActilogDataContext db = ContextSingleton.GetDataContext();

    List<Agir> ListeAgir;

    var v = from i in db.Agir
            where (i.Agir_Contact.Any(a => a.idContact == idContact)
            || i.Projet.Projet_Contact.Any(a => a.idContact == idContact))
            && (i.idEtatIncident == 1 || i.idEtatIncident == 11) && i.Accord == null
            select i;

    ListeAgir = v.ToList();

    return ListeAgir;
}
```

Here is the trace:

```
[InvalidCastException: L'objet doit implémenter IConvertible.]
   System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider) +4049209
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, String defaultValue, TypeCode type, Boolean convertEmptyStringToNull, Boolean ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +126
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, Boolean ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +63
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.get_ParameterValue() +40
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.GetValues(HttpContext context, Control control) +261
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +270
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformSelect() +28
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.DataBind() +364
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.DataBind() +173
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

Comment: Do you have all of them in their respective datatypes, seems to be a mismatch there ?

Comment: All the code within the radgrid was generated automatically when i set the ObjectDataSource. So, i think it's correct!

Comment: Please update the post with the stack trace and are you doing anything special in your select ?

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying to convert any custom objects using the System.Convert class, or RadGrid is trying to do so. If you are passing any custom object to the the grid, implement that type with IConvertible.

Comment: strange, i didn't try to convert anything so far. Actually right now , my code behind is empty.

Comment: Check the binding.. are you specifying correct DataTypes for all the fields?

Answer (score 0):

- [Source](http://www.telerik.com/forums/518500-object-must-implement-iconvertible)

> Your issue could be caused from setting a wrong `DataType` for particular data field. The .NET Framework is trying to cast the type and searching for `IConvertable` interface and throws the exception. In order to resolve your issue you should isolate which column is the problematic and correct the `DataType`. Note that based on the provided code it is hard to determine which column causes the problem because it is not known the types coming from the `ObjectDataSource`.